# Difference between dyadic and suffix notation.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, tensors, index-notation

In some lecture notes I am reading, on introducing suffix notation they write 'up till now we have been using dyadic notation. Now we will use suffix notation' buy I don't really get the difference. I tried looking up dyadic notation, and Wikipedia says that a dyadic is a tensor. I haven't really found anything talking about dyadic 'notation'.

Clarification would be much appreciated!

Comment: If your question is really about mathematics, and not about programming: Certainly clarification would be much appreciated! Tell us about the environment at stake here, and gives some examples of dyadic notation as well as of suffix notation.

Comment: Please add more detail and context to the question (e.g. what lecture notes, what subject, etc...)

Comment: I've had similar difficulty finding a clear definition of "dyadic notation."  I'm reading Grinfeld's Intro to Tensor Analysis and on p. 151, he uses "dyadic notation" in a way that seems to indicate it's notation that fits with typical linear algebra notation (vectors in bold, using symbols for cross and dot products, etc.) as an alternative to tensor notation